# How to set the status on Order to "Activated" in Test Code

Tags: apex, unit-test, fields, order, status

I am trying to create an order in my test code and set its Status field to "Activated". However I get `FAILED_ACTIVATION, Choose a valid status and save your changes. For a new or cloned order, choose Draft`. Thus I can only set it to "Draft".

What do I need to do in order to set the `status` to `Activated`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.

1) I created the Order with a Status of "Draft".

```
Order order = new Order(
            Name='Test Order',
            AccountId = testAccount.Id,
            Status='Draft',
            EffectiveDate = Date.today(),
            Opportunity = testOpportunity,
            Pricebook2Id = testPricebook.Id);
insert order;
```

2) Next update the status and status codes.

```
order.StatusCode = 'A';
order.Status = 'Activated';
update order;
```

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer? It nowhere enters orderItem, doesn't explain variables. This will not work.

Comment: It does work, I don't remember if I had to enter OrderItem or not though.

Answer (score 1):

DML's Orders must start in [Draft status per doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_order.htm?search_text=order)

> When a client application creates an order, the Status Code must be
>   Draft and the Status must be any value that corresponds to a Status
>   Code of Draft. The application can subsequently activate an order by
>   updating it and setting the value in its Status field to an Activated
>   state; however, the Status field is the only field you can update when
>   activating the order.

However, there's an alternate answer here that relies on ApexMocks and SObject Fabrication

1. Use the Json deserialize technique, ably manifested in this nifty [Sobject Fabricator GitHub library](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator)
2. Use a Selector layer to put a class/method between your code's need for SObjects and the actual SOQL.  See [Trailhead Selector Layer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_patterns_dsl/units/apex_patterns_dsl_learn_selector_l_principles).
3. Use [ApexMocks](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks) (another GitHub library) that exploits the Stubbing API and is based on Mockito

The essential approach (see readmes and other web resources, notably [Force.com Enterprise Architecture Second Edition](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/forcecom-enterprise-architecture-second-edition) for elaboration)

- In your testmethod, create mock Order SObjects (no DML) with Status = 'Activated'
- In your real code, be sure to call an OrdersSelector method that fetches the orders of interest. The SOQL is in the selector class/method
- In your testmethod, use ApexMocks to mock the selector class/method. Have the mocking layer (see ApexMocks doc) return the mocked Sobject(s) from the first step

Thus, you are injecting into the runtime a call to a mock layer that when asked to fetch real SObjects actually just returns mocked SObjects.  Your business logic can be tested just fine without worrying about persisting Sobjects prior to `Test.startTest()`. These mocked SObjects can include formula fields, child objects, auto-number fields, audit fields, etc.

Should you need to update the mocked order, you will need to introduce the [Unit Of Work layer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_patterns_sl/units/apex_patterns_sl_learn_uow_principles) ([see Trailhead again](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_patterns_sl/units/apex_patterns_sl_learn_uow_principles)) and then mock the UnitOfWork and use mocks.verify to assert that the updates were done as expected without any actual real database DML.

Now, I wouldn't do this for a one-off, but rather as part of an adoption of ApexMocks into your org.

Answer (score 1):

Worth checking if `Enable Orders` is activated for your profile - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_order_enable.htm&type=5